# org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException (ROOT region in transition)

Tags: hbase, bigdata, sqoop

I'm trying to import some data from mysql into hbase by using sqoop.
When the process running, i got the following error

> ```
> 13/07/23 12:38:58 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
> 13/07/23 12:38:58 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
> 13/07/23 12:38:59 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `pop` AS t LIMIT 1
> 13/07/23 12:38:59 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `pop` AS t LIMIT 1
> 13/07/23 12:38:59 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/local/hadoops
> Note: /tmp/sqoop-hduser/compile/61f2e4f1d24e82a26240a5f1d4872baf/pop.java
> ```
>
> uses or overrides a deprecated API.
>       Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>       13/07/23 12:39:00 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-hduser/compile/61f2e4f1d24e82a26240a5f1d4872baf/pop.jar
>       13/07/23 12:39:00 WARN manager.MySQLManager: It looks like you are importing from mysql.
>       13/07/23 12:39:00 WARN manager.MySQLManager: This transfer can be faster! Use the --direct
>       13/07/23 12:39:00 WARN manager.MySQLManager: option to exercise a MySQL-specific fast path.
>       13/07/23 12:39:00 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Setting zero DATETIME behavior to convertToNull (mysql)
>       13/07/23 12:39:00 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of pop
>       13/07/23 12:39:00 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.5-1392090, built on 09/30/2012 17:52
>   GMT
>       13/07/23 12:39:00 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:host.name=master
>       13/07/23 12:39:00 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.version=1.7.0_15
>       13/07/23 12:39:00 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
>       13/07/23 12:39:00 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/jre
>       13/07/23 12:39:00 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.class.path=/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../conf:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/lib/tools.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/..:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../hadoop-core-1.0.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/aspectjrt-1.6.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/aspectjtools-1.6.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/commons-daemon-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/commons-logging-api-1.0.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/commons-math-2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/commons-net-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/core-3.1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/hadoop-capacity-scheduler-1.0.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/hadoop-fairscheduler-1.0.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/hadoop-thriftfs-1.0.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.12.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.12.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/jdeb-0.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/jersey-json-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/jets3t-0.6.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/junit-4.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/kfs-0.2.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/oro-2.0.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/slf4j-api-1.4.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.4.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/jsp-2.1/jsp-2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/jsp-2.1/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../conf::/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/ant-eclipse-1.0-jvm1.2.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/asm-3.1.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/avro-1.5.3.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/avro-ipc-1.5.3.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/avro-mapred-1.5.3.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/commons-io-1.4.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/commons-math-2.1.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/commons-net-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/core-3.1.1.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/hadoop-core-1.0.4.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/hbase-0.94.8.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/high-scale-lib-1.1.1.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/httpclient-4.1.2.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/httpcore-4.1.3.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/jackson-core-asl-1.7.3.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.7.3.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/jamon-runtime-2.3.1.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/jaxb-api-2.1.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/jersey-json-1.8.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/jopt-simple-3.2.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/jruby-complete-1.6.5.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/jsp-api-2.1-6.1.14.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/junit-4.10-HBASE-1.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/libthrift-0.8.0.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/metrics-core-2.1.2.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/netty-3.2.4.Final.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/slf4j-api-1.4.3.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.4.3.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/snappy-java-1.0.3.2.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/velocity-1.7.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../lib/zookeeper-3.4.5.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../sqoop-1.4.3.jar:/usr/local/sqoops/bin/../sqoop-test-1.4.3.jar:
>       13/07/23 12:39:00 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/local/hadoops/libexec/../lib/native/Linux-amd64-64
>       13/07/23 12:39:00 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
>       13/07/23 12:39:00 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=
>       13/07/23 12:39:00 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Linux
>       13/07/23 12:39:00 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=amd64
>       13/07/23 12:39:00 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=3.5.0-23-generic
>       13/07/23 12:39:00 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=hduser
>       13/07/23 12:39:00 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/home/hduser
>       13/07/23 12:39:00 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/home/hduser
>       13/07/23 12:39:00 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=180000
>   watcher=hconnection
>       13/07/23 12:39:00 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: The identifier of this process is 6256@Master
>       13/07/23 12:39:00 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server ip6-localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to
>   authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
>       13/07/23 12:39:00 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to ip6-localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
>       13/07/23 12:39:00 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server ip6-localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid =
>   0x14009b9169f0009, negotiated timeout = 180000
>       13/07/23 12:39:00 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=180000
>   watcher=catalogtracker-on-org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation@3b48a380
>       13/07/23 12:39:00 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: The identifier of this process is 6256@Master
>       13/07/23 12:39:00 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server ip6-localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to
>   authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
>       13/07/23 12:39:00 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to ip6-localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
>       13/07/23 12:39:00 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server ip6-localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid =
>   0x14009b9169f000a, negotiated timeout = 180000
>       13/07/23 12:49:01 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x14009b9169f000a closed
>       13/07/23 12:49:01 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
>       13/07/23 12:49:01 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException: Unable to
>   find region for  after 10 tries.
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(HConnectionManager.java:991)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:896)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:857)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.finishSetup(HTable.java:233)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.(HTable.java:173)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.catalog.MetaReader.getHTable(MetaReader.java:201)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.catalog.MetaReader.getMetaHTable(MetaReader.java:227)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.catalog.MetaReader.fullScan(MetaReader.java:722)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.catalog.MetaReader.fullScan(MetaReader.java:184)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.catalog.MetaReader.tableExists(MetaReader.java:450)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.tableExists(HBaseAdmin.java:250)
>         at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.HBaseImportJob.jobSetup(HBaseImportJob.java:194)
>         at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:219)
>         at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:545)
>         at org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager.importTable(MySQLManager.java:111)
>         at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:403)
>         at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:476)
>         at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:145)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
>         at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:181)
>         at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:220)
>         at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:229)
>         at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:238)

In the 'regions in transition', i got the following information:
-ROOT-,,0.70236052 state=OFFLINE, ts=Tue Jul 23 12:42:08 WIT 2013 (594s ago), server=null

Can anyone please help me to solve this? I'm out of ideas.
I've got a presentation one week later.
Thank you for the kindness to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some problem with your RegionServer. Perhaps, RegionServer's session has expired or it is dead and hence the HMaster is not able to assign the regions held by this RegionServer. Looking at the RegionServer logs would be helpful. You could probably see in HMaster logs where this region was assigned. Then go to that RegionServer's UI and see if you see the region?

BTW, How many nodes do you have?Is the data too huge to be stored in your current cluster?

Comment: Thanks for the help.
I have 4 nodes, 1 node acts as master and the others as slave.
Yes, my data is realtively nearly huge to be stored.

I have my -ROOT- region unassigned yesterday, it kept stuck in the "regions in transition".
And then, today I've started the master node to work as slave node too, and the import was a success.
I don't know what's wrong in the import process while the master node didn't act as a slave (the -ROOT- region kept unassigned, although i had tried some ways to solve that).

Comment: The problem solved by commenting out localhost (127.0.0.1) in /etc/hosts, and matching the hosts specified in there with which specified in /etc/hostname (in both master and regionservers)